# How do I run any operating system live with pendrive and make a portable os

Tags: installation

I failed to do so.I I am thinking that wherever I take my pendrive I have my own operating system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step 1: Install WinToUSB

Step 2: Create Your Portable Drive

Step 3. Select Your Installer Media

Step 4. Select Your Hard Drive

Step 5. Start the Installation

I hope this will solve your problem..

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do so,

1. Make your pendrive bootable with any third party application. I prefer Rufus.
2. Add your operating system .iso file in Rufus or any other software and run it.
3. It Will take some time to make your pendrive bootable, once the process is completed.
4. Shutdown your PC and open boot menu choose your pendrive and press enter.
5. Your PC will boot into your pendrive, you should be aware of an installation process of Operation system you want to install.